# Lottie not centering while getting expanded

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

I need a Lottie to be fitted to the whole screen, so I set Lottie height and width to `double.infinity`.
But the Lottie getting expanded from top left corner instead of from centre making the centre of lottie slightly moved to the right bottom direction, No matter the alignment. Also tried wrapping in `Center` and `Align`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Lottie.asset(
          'splash_logo.json',
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          repeat: true,
          height: double.infinity,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How to expand it keeping the centre of the Lottie at the Centre of the screen

Comment: None of these approaches work, I am having the same issue. Was it ever solved?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to wrap the Lottie animation in a `Container` and set the height and width of the `Container` to `double.infinity`. This will allow the `Container` to fill the entire screen, and the animation will be centered within this `Container`.

Example;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
     height: double.infinity,
     width: double.infinity,
     child: Center(
       child: Lottie.asset(
         'splash_logo.json',
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         repeat: true,
         height: double.infinity,
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         width: double.infinity,
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
```

Another way is to use the `OverflowBox` widget to allows its child to overflow the parent's box, which can help with alignment issues.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: OverflowBox(
     minHeight: 0.0,
     minWidth: 0.0,
     maxHeight: double.infinity,
     maxWidth: double.infinity,
     child: Center(
       child: Lottie.asset(
         'splash_logo.json',
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         repeat: true,
         height: double.infinity,
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         width: double.infinity,
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
```

## Edit

You could also try the `Stack` widget which allow to stack multiple children widgets on top of each other.

Example;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: Stack(
     children: [
       Lottie.asset(
         'splash_logo.json',
         repeat: true,
         height: double.infinity,
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         width: double.infinity,
       ),
       Center(child: Container()),
     ],
   ),
 );
}
```

Also, I add this `Align` that you've already use, maybe the approach here become different;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Lottie.asset(
       'splash_logo.json',
       repeat: true,
       height: double.infinity,
       fit: BoxFit.cover,
       width: double.infinity,
     ),
   ),
 );
}
```

If neither of these solutions work, it's possible that the issue here is the Lottie itself. The animation might have been created in a way that it's not centered. If so, you might need to recreate the animation or edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue is still there, I tried replacing the Lottie with `Placeholder` widget with size more than parent and it turns out that the issue is with the `Lottie` widget.

Comment: I've edit the answer and add additional approach.